# Button Id Not recognized in MainActivity.kt File Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android App Development, and I was following a tutorial online to use Kotlin to create a basic application. In the tutorial, I got an issue with a button Id not being recognized. The Button has an id "goToAddProduct"
[image]

[image]

In my MainActivity.kt, I call it however I still get an error. I have also tried to do

```
Button homebutton = findViewById(R.id.goToAddProduct)
homebutton.setonClickListener{...}
```

However I have not had any luck yet with that. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. And just remember that I am new to this and don't understand Kotlin that well. Thank you!

Comment: hint: look at your setContentView. full answer, content_main != activity_main

Answer (score 7):

Apply these plugins in  build.gradle(module) file.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue - my solution was to put `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'` into the plugins in the build gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `MainActivity`'s layout is `activity_main` which is set in `setContentView` although you're trying to access views from another layout (content_main.xml)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Kotlin plugin to use the direct id in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

var homebutton : Button = findViewById(R.id.goToAddProduct)
homebutton.setOnClickListener{...} must does work, with O letter in capital.

Answer (score 0):

The way of using the id directly is deprecated.

Try:

`val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.goToAddProduct)`

or

`val button = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.goToAddProduct)`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Kotlin synthetics as it's already deprecated and suggested to migration on viewBinding. Check this refrence to migartion to viewBinding and accessing all references of XML file. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Just Add this in your `build.gradle`

```
 buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

So, you will be directly able to access `goToAddProduct.SetOnClickListener {}`